# Is it possible writing a cross-platform desktop application with XHTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, desktop-application

Is it possible writing a cross-platform desktop application with XHTML (or HTML), CSS and JavaScript?

If the answer is yes, how to run this application? Should I run it with a browser like Firefox?

**Note**: Currently Windows supports [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application).

Comment: If it runs "with a browser" then it's a web application and not a desktop application.

Comment: Will it have a server side, or only client side?

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque: Client side. Just a desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for is the [Open Web Apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Apps)

Answer (score 2):

HTA is really Old technology.

Try tools like Titanium (Appcelerator). They are tools, which render HTML content inside an APP. So, from outside, you will be running an executable but inside , it is loading a HTML file.

Same principle is being used in many apps now a days. Facebook for android is a best example

Answer (score 1):

If client-side JavaScript, and/or HTML/CSS hackery accomplishes the task you wish it to, yes, and with a user agent like Firefox, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With HTML5.

The other answer's solutions are great, but generally they assume that the user is connected to the internet to have a server-side that handles the data.

But it's possible to use Open Web Apps (as ZER0 suggested) with HTML5, which has a lot of support for [offline web apps](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/).

Pay attention to it, though. Even HTML5 assumes that eventually the user will have some sort of internet connection, and offline functionalities are seen as a "cache". So, I'm not sure that this solution is enough for every requirement, because I don't know how much space HTML5 provides to offline applications